# Transition and animation like YouTube

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-recyclerview

So I've been learning and working with android transitions and animations. So I would like to know how can I achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc6Mh.jpg) animation.
I've searched a lot and couldn't find anything. So please help me.

Comment: This is likely a highly customized View that works together with highly customized CoordinatorLayout Behaviours. I doubt that someone will come up with a convenient "code snippet" for that. Here's a good intro on that topic: https://medium.com/@zoha131/coordinatorlayout-behavior-basic-fd9c10d3c6e3

Comment: @muetzenflo thanks, i literally had no clue about custom behaviours.

Comment: you're welcome. Do not fear. They look scary at first, but actually they're quite intuitive once you understand which methods to override for what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came upon the new MotionLayout, which looks really awesome. If you look in the [Google Samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConstraintLayoutExamples) for "**YouTube like motion Example**", you'll find exactly what you were looking for. Plus this is future proof and without an external library.

Comment: Here is even a tutorial about this view: https://medium.com/vrt-digital-studio/picture-in-picture-video-overlay-with-motionlayout-a9404663b9e7

Answer (score 0):

So I found a library in GitHub and it had transitions of previous version of YouTube. So I'll be studying [it's](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel/blob/develop/README.md) source code.